# X11 Forwarding does not work

Tags: terminal, ssh, x11

I installed the latest version of XQuartz and:

- changed `# X11Forwarding no` to `X11Forwarding yes` in `/private/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- enabled *Allow connections from network clients* in XQuartz

When I try to connect to another server via `ssh -X /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 username@host`
in xterm, I get the following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname /users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I ran `ssh -X remote.Unix.system xclock` and the clock was shown, yet I still got the error. How can I fix this?

System:

- MacBook Pro 2018
- macOS Big Sur 11.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try to connect to another server via `ssh -X /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 username@host` in xterm I get the following error

If you wish to specify the private key to use, you need to provide the `-i` option:

```
ssh -X -i /Users/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 username@host
```

Otherwise `ssh` will interpret the path to your private key as the name of the server you are trying to connect to, and will fail with the error message `nodename nor servname provided, or not known`.